# ConTeXt: How can I prevent a block of text from being split over a page break?

Tags: page-breaking, context, context-mkiv

At the end of below minimum working example there is a funny `\startdelimitedtext[endtext]` which should be printed at the bottom of the last page without being split over a page break. How do I render `[endtext]` indivisible?

```
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\setuptolerance[horizontal, tolerant, stretch]

\setupexternalfigures [location=default]

\definedelimitedtext[endtext]
\setupdelimitedtext[endtext][before={\vfill}]

\starttext
  \input douglas.tex

  \input douglas.tex

One line

A second line

And another line

\startendtext
\startalignment[middle]
Written in Hasselt, Belgium!\crlf
\externalfigure[cow][height=31pt]\crlf
This work is licensed under a Creative Cows\crlf Attribution-NonCowmercial-MilkAlike 3.0 Unported License.\crlf
Other licensing available on request. Typesetting by \ConTeXt\ \contextmark.
\stopalignment
\stopendtext

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boxes can't be broken across pages, so it makes sense to use a box
here. The [`\framed`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed) command
and the
[`\startframedtext`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startframedtext)
environment are examples of boxes.

Since you used `\vfill` I assume
the text should be placed at the bottom of the page. This does not
work as expected, since TeX removes the vertical space. This is a side effect of how 
page breaking works in TeX. Usually it's not desired to start a page
with vertical space followed by a paragraph, so TeX removes it.
That's what the `\null` is for. It's an empty box, so the page does start with a box instead of vertical space. The penalty
prevents a page break between this box and the vertical space. Otherwise the 
vertical space would again end up at the top of the page
and removed by TeX.

Furthermore, `\placefloats` ensures that all floats are printed before typesetting `endtext`.

Finally, I replaced your `\crlf` with the [lines
environment](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startlines) which
does respect new lines.

```
\setupexternalfigures
  [location=default]

\defineframedtext
  [endtext]
  [before=\placefloats\null\penalty\plustenthousand\vfill,
   width=fit]

\startbuffer
  \startendtext
    \startlines [align=middle]
      Written in Hasselt, Belgium!
      \midaligned{\externalfigure[cow][height=31pt]}
      This work is licensed under a Creative Cows
      Attribution-NonCowmercial-MilkAlike 3.0 Unported License.
      Other licensing available on request. Typesetting by \ConTeXt\ \contextmark.
    \stoplines
  \stopendtext
\stopbuffer

\starttext
  \dorecurse{9}{\input ward\par}
  \getbuffer

  \page
  \dorecurse{5}{\input ward\par}
  \getbuffer

  \page
  \dorecurse{9}{\input ward\par}
  \getbuffer
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: The first box is at the top of the page! Maybe add a `after=\page` to ensure a pagebreak after the box.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, Marco was a bit eager to show examples by cramming them all in one file. Your remark would indeed correct this. Nonetheless, Marco's answer is correct for this use case.

Comment: @Marco I have added a `\placefloats` at the start of the `begin=` statement.